# ×Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {author, quote}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array

Tags: reactjs, object, error-handling, components

I am trying to pass an object into a React component like so, but receiving the above error:

```
class RandomQuoteBox extends React.Component{
    render(){
      return(
        <div class="container">
          <Quote />
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
              </div>
              <div class="col-8">
                <div class="card" style={{
                  backgroundColor: '#FFDC00',
                  width: '500px',
                  height: '300px',
                  margin: '0 auto'
                  }}>
                    <div>
                      <Author {...QUOTES}/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <Button />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              <div class="col">
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is the Object Quotes:

```
    const QUOTES = [
  {author: 'test 1', quote: 'tester 1'},
  {author: 'test 2', quote: 'tester 2'},
  {author: 'test 3', quote: 'tester 3'},
  {author: 'test 4', quote: 'tester 4'},
  {author: 'test 5', quote: 'tester 5'},
  {author: 'test 6', quote: 'tester 6'},
];
```

And here is the Author function:

```
    const Author =  (props) => {
  return <p>{props.quotes}</p>
}
```

When I pass in an array direct to  in the RandomQuote component, it displays correctly. However I would like to have an outside object that holds both keys, author and quote. Then render the Author and Quote component respectively. (I did not list the Quote component here as once I figure one out I should be able to figure that one out).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for to do is this:

```
<div>
{ QUOTES.map(quote => <Author quote={quote} /> )}
</div>

const Author = quote => {
  return <p>{quote.author} says {quote.quote}<p>
}
```

`QUOTES` is an array, so in order to render it you need to use `map()`.

Comment: How does your `<Author>` component look like now?

Answer (score 0):

The below solution worked for me

```
function AuthorPrint({authors}) {
      return authors.map(author => (
        <p>{author.name}</p>
      ))
    }


<div>
   <AuthorPrint authors={QUOTES}/>
</div>


const QUOTES = [
  {name: 'test 1', quote: 'tester 1'},
  {name: 'test 2', quote: 'tester 2'},
  {name: 'test 3', quote: 'tester 3'},
  {name: 'test 4', quote: 'tester 4'},
  {name: 'test 5', quote: 'tester 5'},
  {name: 'test 6', quote: 'tester 6'},
];
```